# What half episode specials follow Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

I have seen it referenced under a different post that there are four half episode length specials following Brotherhood. I’m in this point of sadness and mass of emotion after finishing the series and just want to see more about their life. Particularly I would like to see Winry and Ed enjoying their relationship as well as see Al. In addition the story never goes to mention what happened to their granny. I’m guessing she died? It seems like she never got to see ed and Al back in their original bodies. I also kind of wonder whether van Holstein died before or after Ed and Al’s reunion with Winry.

Answer (score 4):

The specials are

1. [The Blind Alchemist](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Bonus_Episode:_The_Blind_Alchemist)

   > Edward and Alphonse visit an alchemist who supposedly performed a successful Human Transmutation.
2. [Simple People](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Bonus_Episode:_Simple_People)

   > After Winry meets Riza, she decides to pierce her ears because it "looks good", while Riza, having seen Winry's hair, grows hers longer for the same very simple reason.
3. [The Tale of Teacher](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Bonus_Episode:_The_Tale_of_Teacher)

   > A story of Izumi's "alchemy" survival training in the North region.  This is followed by how Izumi first ran into Sig Curtis, possibly in North City.
4. [Yet Another Man's Battlefield](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Bonus_Episode:_Yet_Another_Man%27s_Battlefield)

   > While in the military academy, Mustang and Hughes befriend an Ishvalan. Unfortunately, they'll soon have to become mortal enemies.

Of them only the second one contains a little bit of content of the relationship between Winry and Ed but it is set before the main events of the series.

> In addition the story never goes to mention what happened to their granny. I’m guessing she died? It seems like she never got to see ed and Al back in their original bodies.

That is not the case. Her [wiki](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Pinako) entry states that

> She is the sole parental figure of the younger generation to see the arrival of Ed and Winry's children.

Comment: To fully address the original question it might be worth mentioning the manga-only epilogue (none of the OVAs "follow" the story, and the epilogue was never animated).

Answer (score 2):

There are four full-length OVA episodes; however, none of them take place post-Brotherhood. The names of the episodes are The Blind Alchemist (a neat little side-story from the manga that was left out of the main story line), Simple People (a really sweet episode about Ed and Winry being dorks, and Winry looking up to Riza), Teacher's Tale (Izumi's really funny backstory. watch it until the end; there is a super funny scene after the credits!), and Yet Another Man's Battlefield (by far my favourite. This episode made me smile and giggle before crushing my heart into tiny little pieces). They are REALLY good so I would recommend watching them!

There is also a joke series called four koma theatre that is based off of the small joke comics Arakawa would make at the end of each chapter.

Granny Pinako survived long enough to see Al's body. In the manga epilogue she is standing in front of Hohenheim and Trisha's grave, so she stayed alive quite a while after Ed and Al return.

Hohenheim likely died before Ed and Al got back to Resembool, because he was dying with only one soul left after the promised day.

There isn't a lot of information about what happens after Brotherhood ends but Arakawa said that Ed and Winry have a lot of kids and are very happy together. One of the animators made [a drawing of Ed and Winry getting married](https://ember53608.deviantart.com/art/EdWin-Royai-Wedding-312656382)  (with Roy and Riza getting married in the background) but I don't know if it counts as canon.

I believe she also said that Roy would eventually become the leader of the country a few years after Brotherhood ends.

Also, Al melts down his old armor to make automail, but he keeps the helmet as a souvenir (there is a really cute comic about it but I don't know where it is).